# PostgreSQL: How to edit data from data output?

Tags: sql, postgresql

On excel I can write simply a formula to subtract a cell from another cell from a chosen data set for instance, I'm struggling to basically do the same thing with PostgreSQL.

I have a dataset which gives a consumer's activity pattern over the past 28 months. The data contains a timestamp recording when and where the consumer is, but it doesn't contain how much time he spent at each location or activity. I've tried using Age functions but since I don't have a column which shows when the consumer left the location, I can't do something like:

```
SELECT AGE(ended_at,virtual_time)
WHERE consumer_id = '93da'
FROM public.consumer
```

The code below gives me the consumer's activity pattern and virtual_time. But I have no idea how to add another column which calculates time spent per activity.

```
SELECT activity, virtual_time
FROM public.consumer
WHERE consumer_id = '93da'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2;
```

I'm trying to calculate the time spent on each activity by somehow using the timestamp records, create a new column which subtracts timestamp no. 2 by timestamp no.1.

For example, something that'll do:

```
   Virtual_Time            Activity      Time_Spent
1) 16/09/2017 17:52:06     Gym           00:34:11 
2) 16/09/2017 18:26:17     Whole Foods   00:05:22
3)...
```

Time spent = timestamps 2 (`16/09/2017 17:52:06`) subtracted by timestamp 1 (`16/09/2017 18:26:17`). Vice versa.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

@GMB:

The code you gave returned this result for the first 8 records:

```
    Virtual_Time              Activity       Time_Spent
1) 2017-09-16 17:52:06     Marks & Spencer   00:00:00
2) 2017-09-16 17:52:06     Marks & Spencer   [NULL] 
3) 2017-09-16 18:26:17     Whole Foods       00:00:00
4) 2017-09-16 18:26:17     Whole Foods       00:34:11
5) 2017-09-16 18:26:19     Whole Foods       00:00:00
6) 2017-09-16 18:26:19     Whole Foods       00:00:02
7) 2017-09-16 18:26:20     Whole Foods       00:00:00
8) 2017-09-16 18:26:20     Whole Foods       00:00:01
```

Not sure why there are NULL values, and it's almost like row no. 4 calculated timestamp no. 4 subtracted by timestamp no. 2. But the rest are not right. And there are a lot of duplicates showing (e.g. rows 3 & 4, rows 5 & 6).

I really appreciate your help. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Add some more sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I've edited the data. I think the new sample might help a little more as to the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need [window function `LAG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) (available starting Postgres 8.4) :

```
SELECT 
    virtual_time, 
    activity, 
    AGE(
        virtual_time, 
        LAG(virtual_time) OVER(PARTITION BY consumer_id ORDER BY virtual_time)
    ) Time_Spent
FROM public.consumer
WHERE consumer_id = '93da'
GROUP BY virtual_time, activity, consumer_id
ORDER BY virtual_time;
```

`LAG()` gives you access to the Nth (default : first) record before the current one in a partition (ie a group of records) given a sort criteria. Here we partition by customer and order by virtual time. The `GROUP BY` clause eliminates  duplicates that come from the original data.

This **[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scyZStGnvCHCaM1h35YS9D/0)** with your 8 records of sample data returns :

```
| virtual_time             | activity      | time_spent                  |
| ------------------------ | ------------- | --------------------------- |
| 2017-09-16T17:52:06.000Z | Marks&Spencer |                             |
| 2017-09-16T18:26:17.000Z | WholeFoods    | {"minutes":34,"seconds":11} |
| 2017-09-16T18:26:19.000Z | WholeFoods    | {"seconds":2}               |
| 2017-09-16T18:26:20.000Z | WholeFoods    | {"seconds":1}               |
```

NB : there cannot be a time spent on the first record, since it has no preceeding record to be compared to.

Comment: It returns back: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "consumer_id"?

Comment: @BetiFransisca : sorry I had a typo where keyword BY was missing in PARTITION BY. I fixed the query, would you please give it another try ?

Comment: You are being so helpful cause I'm finally getting a result. BUT the table doesn't look quite right. I'll edit my question now and show what your code returned.

Comment: I've edited by question showing what your code gave. If you have some time to help PLEASE have a little look. :) Thank you.

Comment: Also, I did GROUP BY, because I wanted to look for per activity, so I don't get duplicates or something.

Comment: @BetiFransisca : I am at work right now, will take a look later on today and update my answer.

Comment: Okay, would REALLY appreciate it if you could help anytime today as I need this working before tomorrow :).